# Is the Twitter bootstrap helper in the Play framework deprecated?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.1

I often use the Twitter bootstrap form template helper in my web application as this is very easy.

Yesterday I want to create a form with horizontal fields and found on GitHub [a Pull-Request](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/217) with a comment (one year old) from guillaumebort that the helper will be deprecated in the next version.But I found nothing about it in the [Play Template helper Documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFormHelpers).

- Is the helper already deprecated or will it get updated?
- Is there already any more sophisticated Bootstrap Template helper as plugin? (I think, *lot* people are using Play+Bootstrap.)
- ...or should I write my own helper with support for horizontal fields?

Comment: An updated discussion is available at http://stackoverflow.com/q/30452387/873282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the Twitter Bootstrap helper is not maintained anymore. By looking at the [history](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commits/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/twitterBootstrap), the latest update on this comes from a year ago. And it is based on an old Twitter Bootstrap version.

I think you should write your own helper.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I have written my own Template helper which is based on the [helper from James Faeldon](http://www.jamesfaeldon.com/2012/05/01/using-twitter-bootstrap-horizontal-forms-in-play-framework-2-0/) and created a new Play2-documentation issue in the bugtracker.